# Erro CS0029 no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo

Estou tentando fazer uma calculadora bem simples, só pra entender como programa funciona, e me deparei com o seguinte problema:

Se coloco 5+5 na calculadora ela me dá o valor de 55 como resposta. Para arrumar isso fui tentar passar os valores digitados para `int`, mas sempre dá o erro:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

```
 private void BtnSoma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResultado.Text = Convert.ToInt32(txtNum1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtNum2.Text); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisa converter para inteiro fazer a conta e depois converter novamente para `string`. Nada garante que será digitado algo correto, e se o dado entrado não for um número inteiro a aplicação quebrará, para corrigir isto precisa ser feito outro código:

```
private void BtnSoma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!int.TryParse(txtNum1.Text, out var valor1) || !int.TryParse(txtNum2.Text, out var valor2)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Pelo menos um dos valores é inválido", "Entrada inválida", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        return;
    }
    lblResultado.Text = (valor1 + valor2).ToString(); 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CNswY1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NnX3Lu). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/StringToInt.cs). Ligeiramente diferente para sere facilmente testável online.